# How to express a signal in terms of Riesz bases?

Tags: signal-processing, wavelets

Fast discrete wavelet transform allows us to express any discrete signal in terms of wavelet bases by convolution with filter coefficients. How can one express a digital signal in terms of biorthogonal Riesz bases efficiently ?